# How to always get a whole number if we divide two integers in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have three integer type variable

1. Totallistcount
2. totalpagescount
3. perpagecount

Suppose at initial level i have this

```
Totallistcount = 14;
perpagecount = 9;
```

Now I have a formula to found total number of pages possible

```
totalpagescount = Totallistcount / perpagecount ;
```

but in this situtation I got `1` in `totalpagescount` but I need `2` in `totalpagescount` , because 9 items on the first page and rest of item will be displayed on last page , How can I do this

Thanks ,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
totalpagescount = (Totallistcount + perpagecount - 1) / perpagecount ;
```

Comment: Heh... I thought of adding the page count, realised it would break when the total count was already a multiple, and went "meh" instead of trying to figure it out properly.

Comment: +1 This is brilliant an idea, I've never though about it in this way... I'm curious though... What would be the performance difference between this solution and using `Ceiling`-like-solution.

Answer (score 5):

This is how integer division **should** work, you need to convert it to [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) first to be able to get the number and then use [`Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx) to "round it up":

```
(int)Math.Ceiling( (double)Totallistcount / perpagecount);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to round up, you need to perform the division as a floating point number, then call `Math.Ceiling` to get the next-highest whole number.

```
double quotient = Totallistcount / (double)perpagecount;
double ceiling = Math.Ceiling(quotient);
int totalpagescount = (int)ceiling;
```

Answer (score 1):

an other solution :

> int pageCount = (records - 1) / recordsPerPage + 1;

int pageCount = (14 - 1) / 9 + 1;
=> pagecount = 2